# Is paramemterless connect valid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I sometimes see the following in our code:

```
@connect(() => ({}))
export default class SomeClass extends Componet {
  (...)
};
```

I would understand if `connect` was taking any arguments, e.g. `state`, but does it have any purpose when it's parameter-less?

Comment: it Injects to component just dispatch. You can access dispatch in component through this.props.dispatch. Api docs https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#examples

Comment: @Utro sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: I'm fairly certain `@connect(() => ({}))` is the same as `@connect()`.

Comment: @Utro yeah, please put it as an answer if you are sure that this is all to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Injects to component just dispatch function.
You can access dispatch in component through `this.props.dispatch`.

Api docs [github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#examp‌​les](http://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#examp%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bles)

if you don't map any slice of state to props, **you should use connect()**, otherwise it doesnt make any sense. Connected component will be notified , and  it will invoke checking shalow equality of new stateProps  and previous stateProps.